How to solve the integral $\iint_D(x^2+y^2)^{-2} dxdy$ with where $D$ is $x^2+y^2\leq2, x\geq 1$ and after that the same integral but with $x\leq1$.
So my main question is after I use the Jacobian how do I write the new space $D^*$ when I substitute $x=r\cos θ$ and $y=r\sin θ$. I know that I will find what the range of $θ$ is by simply finding the values of $θ$ where the line $x=1$ intersects the circle $x^2+y^2=2$ which are $\pi/4$ and $-\pi/4$ but what will the $r$ integration limits be? Will they be from $0$ to $1/\cosθ$? and if so why?
Moreover, it would be really helpful if someone could answer what the approach should be if the problem said the following five;

$x\leq1$ instead of $x\geq1$
$y\leq1$ instead of $x\geq1$
$y\leq1$ instead of $x\geq1$
$x+y\leq1$ instead of $x\geq1$
$x+y\geq1$ instead of $x\geq1$


$r^2\leq2\Longrightarrow 0\leq r\leq \sqrt{2}$ and $r\cos\theta\geq 1\Longrightarrow\arccos\frac{1}{r}\leq \theta\leq 2\pi-\arccos\frac{1}{r}$

You can also let theta go from $0$ to $2\pi$ and calculate boundaries from $r$ in terms of \theta (ideally by splittingthe range of $\theta$ integral into the part where $r$ is constant and the part where it is not)

This question doesn't belong on this site though. You should ask one question "per question" and this question is not well researched. I suggest you review your notes on how to parametrise areas or watch for example some Khan academy videos on the topic

Start by drawing a picture and asking yourself: In the region of interest, what is the range of $\theta$? For each fixed $\theta$, what are the limits of $r$ in this region — that is, at what value of $r$ in terms of $\theta$ does the ray from the origin enter and at what value of $r$ in terms of $\theta$ does the ray exit the region?

I am asking because one would think  that it is an easy question but I was really taken aback, because when I drew the circle and the line you can clearly see that it the r value is not from 0\leq r\leq \sqrt{2} but from 1 to sqrt{2} and that is why I don't really understand why your explanation holds true Vincent! Also I think it's a great question to ask here because it groups every other circle with line intersection D possible which generalizes the solution and what the approach should be, I didn't say you have to engage with that 2nd part too! But anyway thanks for the engagement at least

Also Vincent I don't understand why you are saying that my question doesn't belong here, what I optionally asked about a way to generalize the first part of my question. so I don't really understand why you had to down vote the question like it's not really that helpful for calc 3 students that have the same question as I do

In the case $D_1=\{x^2+y^2\le 2,\, x\ge 1\}$, using the symmetry of $f(x,y)$ you can consider $y\ge 0$. The line $x=1$ and the circle intersect at the point $(1,1)$, so $\theta \in [0,\pi/4]$. Now, since $0\le r\le\sqrt 2$ and $r\cos \theta \ge 1$, you have $\sec \theta \le r \le \sqrt 2$. So the integral becomes:
$$\iint_{D_1}f(x,y)dxdy=2\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_{\sec \theta}^{\sqrt 2} \frac 1{r^3} drd\theta= \frac14 $$
To compute the integral over the region $D_2=\{x^2+y^2\le 2,\, x\le 1\}$, you can compute the integral over the whole circle and then use the additivity of the integral.
